# How to sort big file without using the disk,network or virtual memory?

Tags: algorithm

Yesterday, I attended an interview for network security position and this question was asked:

**Let's say you have a PC with 1GB RAM and the disk of this computer holds a 10 GB file which contain random numbers. What technique will you use for sorting the file and propose algorithm. You cannot be using the disk or network or virtual memory for sorting?**

I tried many different ways as I could think of, proposed  External sorting  but the interviewer  said that this was not the right way. At the end of the interview I ask him politely what is the way and the algorithm for the question he ask me but he refused to say like it was some kind of big secret.

My question  is how would anyone approach this kind of problem cause i just can't stop thinking about it but still no clear answer?

Comment: One thing you left out of your question (and perhaps you were supposed to ask): what, if any, are the bounds on the numbers in the file?

Comment: other questions are: what are metrics for the "best" algorithm? Is it really just speed? If it's speed, the optimum algorithm would depend on speed relation between disk storage and RAM.

Comment: The point is that with the info you've got, there's no single "right" approach. The interviewer tested your ability to apply boring theoretical knowledge and recognize problems, and discuss solutions within the boundaries of a given problem.

Comment: Well I think becasue of this question they they decided not to choose me. gb and GB keyboard mistake caps off.

Comment: To my way of thinking, "this is a dumb, misleading question." If you're going to sort anything, you must have some storage pool, and there are three options: disk, (virtual) memory, and network attached storage. If the person said that all three options are excluded, I've no idea what the answer would be, and that's precisely how I would have responded to the question.

Comment: All the questions I was asked were primley and only connected with networks and this was the last one which was very strange. That's why I can't stop searching and thinking for the right answer.

Comment: @Rockstar don't put your heart too much into this question. You can really think of it as a trick question without right answer. Mike is right, if you can't even use the disk, how would you read the file?

Comment: @Drew what's this? It seems disruptive, and totally out of place

Comment: @MarcusMüller it is Community Moderation

Comment: @Drew hm, not in the sense that I understand moderation!

Comment: Oh, is it really so bad when I call it what I did?  Then, let's just say that it's not a "productive, fruitful" question. I don't appreciate questions that seem to exist only to make you sweat.  And I am very quick to answer them, "I have no idea."

Comment: Ah, the question in the interview, not the op question, my bad.

Comment: ok, let's delete all our comments revolving around wording/snarkiness/moderation, and keep everything clean and everyone happy :)

Comment: @chepner hit the nail on the head. If your range is sufficiently limited, you only need to count the occurrences of each number.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To sort the file you will need to run your algorithm inside the RAM.  Because the file is 10x larger than the available amount of RAM, you will need to sort the file into 10 (or more) separate chunks, and recombine them at the end.

Your algorithm would need to consist of..

1. Read through the list on Disc looking for the largest number in the file (and keep track of it after reading through the list)
2. After reading through the entire list place this number into a list on the RAM and repeat this process (each time looking for the biggest number smaller than the last) until all or most of the RAM is used up.
3. Now add that list back onto Disc with an index representing its order, in this case 1, and clear up the RAM for more processing
4. Repeat step 3 10x or more each time building a list of sorted numbers on RAM, until all numbers have been added to a seperate list on Disc.
5. To finish up, check the indexes on the beginning of each list and (one list at a time) place them into their correct order on the Disc

**Update:** 
I'm adding to my answer to reflect some points made by @JimMischel

The algorithm in RAM would not just be keeping track of the biggest number, but also maintaining a separate integer count that would be incremented with every subsequent occurrence of the number on the file.  The number would then be placed on the sub-list in RAM however many times the number occurs.

**Update:** Concerning the asker's question

The question posted by the OP states that "you cannot use the disc for **Sorting**".  The question says nothing that would imply disc cannot be used for storage.  I believe most reading the question interpreted this the wrong way and thus, without having a place to store any data, presumed the assigned task to be impossible.

Comment: I don't believe the interviewer was stating that the Disc couldn't be accessed at all, because obviously this would make retrieving data from the Disc impossible.  Just that the Disc could not be used to process the sorting.

Comment: (The idea is _almost_ perfect: in each run, do not keep _one_ top priority number, but as many as RAM can hold (using a suitable data structure). With the input range smallish, but still not enough RAM to hold all counters of a counting sort, the approach is analogous.)

Comment: You'll also want to be careful of duplicates. Handling duplicates with this algorithm adds an interesting little twist.

Comment: When I stated that a number should be added to the top of the list, it was meant to be an index representing the sub-lists order in the eventual merged list, adding more than one would be redundant.

Comment: When reading through the Disc, the next number to be added would be a number that equaled the previous number or the next biggest number.  Numbers could then be deleted from Disc after being placed into the list on RAM. @JimMischel

Comment: @Luke: That only works if you can modify the original file. Typically, that's not what a sorting program does. It's not necessary, though: just keep track of the last value *and* the position in the file where you found it. So if you find an equal item on a subsequent pass, you only select if its position is greater. Another way is to maintain a count of the current smallest item. So if there are 7 3's in the file, at the end of the pass where 3 is the smallest, you'd write 7 3's to the output. Rather than going through the file 7 times, once for each 3.

Comment: Both of those would work without modifying the contents on Disc. @JimMischel